# how to connect SQL Server .ndf file to visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and want to connect my .ndf file with Visual Studio 2013.

Is It Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. For starters, you connect to a database that is hosted by an instance of a SQL Server engine. There is no concept of connecting directly to a data file, primary (mdf) or otherwise (ndf, ?df). You also cannot connect directly to an ndf file without the primary (mdf) file. Metadata about the database (including files and locations) along database objects are stored in the mdf so without that, you can't even start your database.